# Can anyone explain these conclusions? Permutations, Symetric group...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, permutations

The conclusions start off like this:I will highlight what is unclear in yellow.
$sgn G$-sign of G permutation, $Ker$-kernel of a function

Lets  define the function: $\ \Phi$ like: $(\forall G \in S_n)\ \  \Phi(G)=sgn G$

$$Ker \Phi=\{ G \in S_n | \Phi(G)=1\}=A_n$$

> $$S_n /  Ker\Phi \cong C_2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (C_2=\{-1 ,
>  1\})  $$ $$ |S_n/ A_n|=|C_2|=2$$

Then we define the function:

> $$(\forall G \in A_n)f(G)= G \cdot \tau , \ \ \ \ \ \\ \tau \rightarrow \text{odd permutation}\\ **\text{**It is easy to prove that f is a
>  bijection**}** \\ |A_n|=|S_n \setminus A_n|=\frac{n!}{2}$$

Comment: Do you know the first isomorphism theorem? The first yellow box follows directly from that; you just need to explain why the sign function is surjective.

Comment: In the first block you should write $S_n/A_n$ (quotient) instead of $S_n \setminus A_n$ (difference). What is your question about the second block, though? $f$ is a bijection because its inverse is $g(G) = G \cdot \tau^{-1}$, but this has nothing to do with $|A_n| = n! / 2$, which is a direct consequence of $S_n / A_n = 2$ and [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)).

Comment: Thank you very much, everything is crystal clear now..

Comment: You have some mistakes in the last line: $|A_n| \neq |S_n/A_n| =2$

Comment: @2000 No, the last line was correct: since $A_n$ has order $2$ in $S_n$ (by the previous block) it follows that $A_n$ has exactly one coset, $S_n \setminus A_n$, and both have cardinality $|S_n|/2 = n!/2$.

Comment: @A.P.:O! Then there is typo here. The correct is $|A_n|=|S_n \setminus A_n| $ not $ |S_n/A_n|$